# ListView bug on Lollipop - tapping on item near fast scroll bar leads to long press

Tags: android, android-listview

I have multiple Activities containing `ListView` like in the screenshot below.

[image: ListView]

When I tap on the "3-dot" area, i.e. near the fast-scroll bar, it leads to a long-press, and activates my multi-select mode.

[image: Unwanted long press]
[image: Multi-select]

However, if I were to move the 3-dot icon to the left of the ListView item, I get a `PopupMenu` as programmed.

I've tested the app on two of my Lollipop 5.1.1 devices and the bug exists in both.

The weird thing is that this weird behavior doesn't happen if I have the ListView in a `Fragment` in a `ViewPager`.

I am completely lost because there doesn't seem to be anything I could do to fix the issue, execpt maybe to place the "3-dot" nearer to the middle since the scrollbar touch area is VERY large.

Has anybody also experienced this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issuer with the fastscroll touch area being to wide. I found a workaround, check my solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34929010/628718

Edit: Just to give the answer a little bit of independence from the given link, the idea is to disable fast-scroll when scrolling is stopped using `OnScrollListener` and `mListView.setFastScrollEnabled(boolean enabled)`.

Comment: Thanks. I think your workaround would work. I've moved on to RecyclerView now though.